# Ubuntu 16.04.7 server latest package updates/upgrades now cause xpdf segmentation fault

Tags: upgrade

Having problems opening PDF with xpdf after the latest Ubuntu Server 16.04.7 package upgrades.

me@server:~$ xpdf mobo.pdf

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

me@server:~$ dpkg -l | grep xpdf

ii  xpdf                                          3.04-1ubuntu1.1                                 amd64        Portable Document Format (PDF) reader

Compare to Raspberry Pi running Raspian which has no problems running xpdf:

root@rpi4:/home/me# dpkg -l | grep xpdf

ii  xpdf                                 3.04-13                             armhf        Portable Document Format (PDF) reader

The error on Ubuntu has been duplicated on a desktop machine, also after the latest updates.
Before the latest updates xpdf was running fine.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to load these libraries:

libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler58 poppler-utils xdg-utils

xpdf is now working.

Seems xpdf is no longer included in Ubuntu 20.04 ?